# Hiding Elements Permanently

Tags: javascript, html

I have two buttons, "Yes" and "No". If user clicks on "Yes", I want to display a message that needs to be permanent.

Eg - I click on yes,the message should stay even after page reload or the next time the user logs in. It shouldn't appear again. Maybe possible if i delete the file or something.

I am able to hide all elements using hide() and then display a msg, but onpage reload, they come back..

Can you guys help?

Thanks

Comment: "It shouldn't appear again" - What shouldn't appear again? "they come back" - they who?

Comment: If your using a dynamic backend, you could make that option a "preference" so your backend will pass a variable whenever you render your page (template). If you wanted to make it a preference for the user.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible using html5's `localstorage` (but I've no experience in using that), or using the [jQuery `cookie` plugin](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/textshadow.html).

```
$(document).ready(
  function(){
    var msg = $.cookie('yesMsg');
    $('#messages').text('yesMsg');

    $('#messageSelectionDiv').click(
      function(){
         $.cookie('yesMsg',$(this).text() {expires: 30});
    });
  });
```

Comment: HTML5 isn't yet a feasible option for compatibility with IE 6 7 and 8.

Comment: great..so this basically stores a cookie. right? is it possible if i enter the user action in db n next time search db n if it returns true, display something else?

Comment: @Jake, that's my general opinion, but it will -at some point- become a viable option, and since (hopefully) this answer will persist until that time it seemed worth mentioning, if only for general interest. @Ryan, it does indeed store a cookie. I'm not quite sure what you mean in your second sentence; either clarify (by adding it to your question via the 'edit' link below your question), or post a separate question.

Comment: @Jake localStorage is supported in IE8.

Comment: @ryan: it's a period measured in days; but I don't *think* that there is a specified maximum number that can be assigned.

Answer (score 0):

If the browser you are targeting supports HTML5, You can use HTML5 localStorage, otherwise cookies, to store some permanent data for the user.

For example:

```
if (localStorage['show_something'])
  // Show it
else
  // Hide it
```

To store it initially, you just set it:

```
  localStorage['show_something'] = true;
```

For more info, refer to this awesome doc:
http://www.html5rocks.com/tutorials/offline/storage/